# Using wildcard inside case statement in bash

Tags: bash, wildcard

I'm making a simple bash script. It accepts 2 options (-d and -f). I would like to allow also the long version of this options (-directory and -file). I tried using the curly brackets wildcard but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash

while test $# != 0
do
  case $1 in
  -f)
    # do something
    ;;
  {-d,-directory})
    # do something
    ;;
  *)
    echo "error"
    ;;
  esac
  shift
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a pipe symbol:

```
case $1 in
    -f)
        # do something
        ;;
    -d|-directory)
        # do something
        ;;
    *)
        echo "error"
        ;;
 esac
```

The various options within a case statement are all shell script *patterns*, where a *pattern*  can actually be several patterns separated by this pipe symbol `|`. You can also use regular expressions in this pattern, for example

```
-[dD]|-directory)
```

would match both `-d`, `-D` and `-directory`.

Comment: And perhaps you will be interested in `getopt` for parsing command line parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
-d|-directory)
    # do something
    ;;
```

But you should think about using a double dash to match 'long options' like in `--directory`.

Comment: Yes, double dash is better! Thanks